# Is it haram to sell virtual points in video games for betting?

Tags: gambling, religion

As a game developer, I've been offered a job involving a video game where players can purchase virtual points with real money, which cannot be exchanged for real money. The points are only used for playing games online, and free points are also given to all players daily. The game allows two players to bet their points, and the winner receives all the points/coins. I believe this is a form of gambling, but I'm uncertain.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s begin by considering the English definition of gambling. The Oxford Dictionary defines gambling as the act of playing games of chance for money

The prohibition of gambling in Islam comes from the Quran. Allāh states clearly in Surah al Ma’idah,

But betting is also prohibited but yes this game is haram as it encourages and teaches betting and gambling

I got most of the things I said from a website called "The halal life"

If you have any questions please reply 
Have a nice day